# How to find probability function that maximizes entropy of probability under constraints?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Given

1. $R=\{r_1,...,r_n\}$ where n is finite and all r are positive integers
2. positive integer b

How can I find a probability function $P=\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ such that :

1. $sum(P*R)=b$ ([expected value][1] equals b)
2. $sum(Plog(1/P))$ is maximized ([entropy][2] is maximized)

Answer (score 1):

Use Lagrange multipliers, via $$J(p_1,\ldots,p_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \log p_i +\lambda(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i p_i - b).$$

It yields that the optimal distribution is of the form
$$
p_k= \frac{e^{\lambda r_k}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda r_i}} 
$$
In general, this has to be solved numerically, to ensure it satisfies the constraint on expectation. The normalisation is taken care of by the division. Of course, the integer constraints mean that a solution may not exist under some conditions.

**Edit:** As I said a solution may not exist. For example, forgetting the normalization and the expectation for now, let $(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(1,3,4).$ This will give $p_1=e^{\lambda},p_2=e^{3\lambda},$ and $p_3=e^{4\lambda}.$ For simplicity put $x=e^{\lambda}.$ Then you are required to have
$$
\frac{x+3x^3+4x^4}{x+x^3+x^4}=b,
$$
(the numerator now comes in to make the probabilities add up to one).
Simplifying we have
$$
x((b-1)+(b-3)x^2+(b-4)x^3)=0,
$$
but this polynomial may not have a positive real solution (required since $x=e^{\lambda}$) for the given $b.$

Actually, I was stupid. Note that for a well-posed problem the expectation $b$ has to be (clearly!) in the interval $[1,4]$ (and in general in the interval from the minimum to the maximum of the $r_i$). The boundary cases have a trivial distribution supported only on one point. Otherwise, let $b\in (1,4)$ and note that by continuity there will be a solution in positive $x$ to the equation.

Comment: how can i find lambda? whats the equation for it?

Comment: set $\sum_{k=1}^n r_k p_k = b$ with $p_k$ as I give above, and numerically solve for lambda, there is no other generic way.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure you didnt miss anything? i tried that and it didnt work, see edit

Comment: You won't be able to solve the equation numerically until you have assigned *specific numerical* values to *all* the quantities in the equation that are supposed to be already known—namely, $\ b\ $, $\ n\ $, and $\ r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n\ $ (and $\ e\ $, if that's not available as a named constant in whatever software you're using).

Comment: I did exactly as you sggested and it didnt work... i got P*R=~5400 while b equaled 10...

Comment: As kodlu notes in [the edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3525371/revisions) to his answer, it is possible for the equation $\ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n r_k e^{\lambda r_k}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda r_i}}=b\ $ to have no solution.

Comment: However, since $\ \lim_\limits{\lambda\rightarrow-\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n r_k e^{\lambda r_k}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda r_i}}=$$\min_\limits{1\le k\le n}r_k\ $ and $\ \lim_\limits{\lambda\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n r_k e^{\lambda r_k}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda r_i}}=\max_\limits{1\le k\le n}r_k\ $, then by the intermediate value theorem, it must have a solution if $\ \min_\limits{1\le k\le n}r_k<$$ b< $$\max_\limits{1\le k\le n}r_k\ $.

Comment: So if these latter conditions are satisfied by the parameters in your problem, then the failure of your script to find a solution must be due to a deficiency in the algorithm it's using.